# http security on Android hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, security, http

I am developing an Android hybrid app

The client side is written in JavaScript and html, and the device is listening on 50001 using `AsyncHttpServer` of https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

The http server implements `/doSomething`- how do I prevent external apps (including the device browser) to call http://localhost:50001/doSomething ?

The hybrid app should be the only one able to call this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You can only make it more difficult.

One way of making it more difficult is to embed a key value in the app, and require the app to pass that value to the service.  Then only apps that know the value can do that.  Of course if you do this its trivial to decompile your app and find the value to spoof you.

To be more secure, you can implement authentication-  encrypt the channel via ssl and have the user log in via a password.  This will make it so that only an authorized user can use you service-  but it wouldn't stop an authorized user from using another app to call that URL.

Comment: What about access control? can I set the http server to accept calls only from the domain of the WebView?

Comment: There is nothing 1 web view can do that another can't fake.  All you can do is have a secret shared between them to tell you that a request is authorized-  and if the secret is in the app then it can be compromised if anyone cares to.  Now if you control the hardware you can do a bit with special ASICs and cryptographic storage to require someone to hack the hardware instead of the software.  But my guess is these aren't specially built phones you're on.  So you're stuck with the user knowing a secret, which means he can authorize any program.

Comment: The "user" in my case is the JavaScript code of the hybrid app, I'm fine with it knowing the secret, I just wondering - how can I let it know about the secret without exposing it to on the client side.

Comment: As per the original answer: you can't. If your architecture depends on trusting a client-side app, your architecture is unsafe and needs to be changed.